# How do I start an activity in the background and close it immediately?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

So I have a `SettingsActivity` that will launch my `SettingsFragment` when the user clicks on the settings button in `MainActivity`. For my `SettingsFragment`, when the user launches the screen for the first time, it will activate the `AlarmManager` I have set it up. This defaults to on when the user signs in for the first time. The user does have the option to turn off notifications.

Now, if the user never goes to the settings screen, it will never activate the `AlarmManager`. How do I start the `SettingsActivity` in the background where it doesn't actually show the UI of the `SettingsActivity` or `SettingsFragment` and then close the `SettingsActivity`/`SettingsFragment` immediately so it's not running in the background forever? I just want to start it up when the user logs in for the first time or logs back in again so the app knows the state of the `AlarmManager` whether it's on or off. If it doesn't know the state, the user will never get any notifications until the user manually clicks on the settings button.

Comment: Why Do you Not start the AlarmManager on Appstart?

Comment: @JohnDoe All the code for the `AlarmManager` is in `SettingsFragment`.

Comment: @TomDarious so why you just call the code from MainActivity or the first entry point

Comment: @HussienFahmy The first entry point isn't `SettingsFragment`. It's `SplashActivity` and that will determine whether to go to the `MainActivity` or `LoginActivity`. And how would I be able to call the code from a separate activity that isn't associated with the `SettingsFragment`?

Comment: You said you would like to set the alarm manager when the user sign in for the first time, som move the logic of alarm manager to LoginActivity to execute after signing in

Comment: @HussienFahmy The problem with that is I won't be able to know the state of the `SwitchPreference` used to turn on and off the `AlarmManager`. That's why `SettingsFragment` has all the code because it extends `PreferenceFragmentCompat()`.

Comment: @Tom Darous to post my answer can I know which language you use? Java or Kotlin

Comment: @HussienFahmy Kotlin

Comment: It's a setting. Save the state into a preference. If you read it out in other activities you can define a default value. And put the Code in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

First, understand the activity lifecycle: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

You can finish your activity at any time (for example onResume()) by calling finish(). You can also use a Timer, a Handler or an Alarm to finish() it at a different time.

In order to make your activity transparent / invisible, don't inflate it with any kind of layout. I would also recommend adding the following lines to the manifest for your activity:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

Regarding the ability to start this activity without any kind of user interaction... you may want to use a Service and startActivity() from there (and potentially also finish() it).

That said, from what you are describing I think you are designing this in a very complicated way and may run yourself down a rabbit hole.

Answer (score 0):

You should let your SettingActivity be your SettingActivity.

When you not use SQLITE or something else to store settings: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Putting all your Code into the SettingFragment should not be your Solution. You could something like this do:

```
return this.sharedPreferences.getBoolean(context.getResources().getString(R.string.preference_stateAlarmmanager), false); // returns false if the preference not yet exists
```

Just read your property and execute your code to start the alarmmanager in case it's true